# Jasper Report how to create an excel xlsx file with RTL sheet?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

We are using jasper version 6. We can export to EXCEL ( XLS and XLSX) .

Below code works for XLS and creates a RTL sheet:

```
 exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
 exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(out));
 SimpleXlsReportConfiguration xlsReportConfig = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
 xlsReportConfig.setSheetDirection(RunDirectionEnum.RTL);
 exporter.setConfiguration(xlsReportConfig);
```

However when I try the same code to make a XLSX file the sheet direction will not change to RTL:

```
exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(out));
SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration xlsxReportConfiguration =  new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
xlsxReportConfiguration.setSheetDirection(RunDirectionEnum.RTL);
exporter.setConfiguration(xlsxReportConfiguration);
```

Comment: Which is the exact version of Jasper report that you have tired?, found  same bug in v 6.1.1

Answer (score 2):

I finally used below code ( It is costy but works) , which is mentioned at https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/523041/right-left-arabic-reports

```
public class ReportUtils {
    
    private ReportUtils(){
        
    }
    /**
     * mirror each page layout
     * @param print
     */
    public static void mirrorLayout(JasperPrint print) {
        int pageWidth = print.getPageWidth();
        for (Object element : print.getPages()) {
            JRPrintPage page = (JRPrintPage) element;
            mirrorLayout(page.getElements(), pageWidth);
        }
    }

    /**
     * mirror a list of elements
     * @param print
     */
    protected static void mirrorLayout(List<?> elements, int totalWidth) {
        for (Iterator<?> it = elements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            JRPrintElement element = (JRPrintElement) it.next();
            int mirrorX = totalWidth - element.getX() - element.getWidth();
            element.setX(mirrorX);

            if (element instanceof JRPrintFrame) {
                JRPrintFrame frame = (JRPrintFrame) element;
                mirrorLayout(frame.getElements(), frame.getWidth());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
Exporter exporter;

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(out));

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,
                    params, dataSource != null ? new JRMapArrayDataSource(
                            dataSource) : new JREmptyDataSource());
ReportUtils.mirrorLayout(jasperPrint);

exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporter.exportReport();
return out.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a **bug** in the **jasper report** library tested with **v 6.1.1**, adding code below after export it will work correctly (with poi libraries included in jasper report distribution, so no bug in POI...).

```
//out is the file after jasper report export
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(out));
int ns = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
for (int i = 0; i < ns; i++) {
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
    sheet.setRightToLeft(true);
}
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(out);
workbook.write(outStream);
outStream.close();
```

[Current bug report tracker on jaspersoft community](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/6566)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem generating a report in XLSX, in the last version of JasperReports 6.1, but this code works for me:

Firstly, i configure the jasper print

```
    JRSwapFile swapFile = new JRSwapFile(".", 1024, 1024);
    JRVirtualizer virtualizer = new JRSwapFileVirtualizer(100, swapFile, true);
    parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, virtualizer);

    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(stream, parameters, dbConnection);
    List<JasperPrint> prints = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
    prints.add(print);
```

After that, i configure the output for the generated report, in my case the report will be managed in memory by an ByteArrayOutputStream:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

I create an instance of JRXlsxExporter for generate a file with the .xslx extension, and putting the printers and the output:

```
    JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
    exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(prints));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(output));
```

The next step is to create the report configuration for the exporter, when i put this code my report works!, so you must use it!:

```
    SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration xlsxReportConfiguration =  new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
    xlsxReportConfiguration.setSheetDirection(RunDirectionEnum.RTL);
    exporter.setConfiguration(xlsxReportConfiguration);
```

Finally, generate the report and close the outputStream:

```
    exporter.exportReport();
    output.flush();
    output.close();
```

I hope that this works for you